# Get characters from the left until space then one more character after it

Tags: php

I want to get all of the text from the left and go until there is a space and then get one more character after the space.

example:
***"Brian Spelling"*** would be ***"Brian S"***

How can I do this in php?

In ASP the code looks like this:

```
strName1=left(strName1,InStr(strName1, " ")+1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
$strName1 = "Brian Spelling";
$strName1 = substr($strName1, 0, strpos($strName1, ' ')+2);
echo $strName1;
```

prints

```
Brian S
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Find the index of the space with [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)
2. Extract the string from the beginning to that index + 2 with [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Also consider how you might need to update your logic for names like:

- H. G. Wells
- Martin Luther King, Jr.
- Cher

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! this is almost better then the examples others have provided.

Answer (score 2):

Split your string with `explode` function and substring the first character of the second part with `substr` function.

```
$explodedString = explode(" ", $strName1);

$newString = $explodedString[0] . " " . substr($explodedString[1], 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "Brian Spelling";
$element = explode(' ', $string);
$out = $element[0] . ' ' . $element[1]{0};
```

and just for fun to take Rob Hruska's answer under advisement you could do something like this:

```
$skip = array( 'jr.', 'jr', 'sr', 'sr.', 'md' );
$string = "Martin Luther King Jr.";
$element = explode(' ', $string);
$count = count( $element );
if( $count > 1)
{
    $out = $element[0] . ' ';
    $out .= ( in_array( strtolower( $element[ $count - 1 ] ), $skip ) )
        ? $element[ $count - 2 ]{0} : $element[ $count - 1 ]{0};
} else $out = $string;
echo $out;
```

-just edited so "Cher" will work too

Add any suffixes that you want to skip add to the $skip array

Answer (score 1):

Regexp - makes sure it hits the second word with /U modifier (ungreedy).

```
$t = "Brian Spelling something else";
preg_match( "/(.*) ./Ui", $t, $r );
echo $r[0];
```

And you get "Brian S".

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code

```
$name="Brian Lara"
$pattern = '/\w+\s[a-zA-Z]/';
preg_match($pattern,$name,$match);
echo $match[0];
```

Ouput

```
Brian L
```